# Swift Webview force landscape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, orientation

I create a webview in xCode with Swift. Now I want some pages that the screen force rotates to landscape. And some pages auto orientation. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I did this after the answer of Reinier:

```
func loadAddressURL(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

    //url name another will show in landscape mode
    if(request.URL?.absoluteString == baseUrl + "dashboard")
    {
        print(request.description)

        if(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation != UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

        }
    }

    WebView.loadRequest(request)
```

But it doesn't work. When I turn my device to portrait, the app rotate to portrait but I want to force landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been working on your question, and this are my results, first of all you need to be notified when the event of load new URL happens with this method you can achieve this, of course you need to set as delegate of your webView your viewController and then implement this method

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

this is the code

### UPDATED

to keep this orientation you need to implement this method `func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` and keep in one variable the orientation that you want

---

Swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    var termsWeb = false
    var validOrientation : UIInterfaceOrientationMask = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.loadWebView()
    }

    @IBAction func loadAnotherWeb(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.loadWebView()
    }

    func loadWebView()
    {
        let termsFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("terms_conditions", ofType: "html")
        do
        {
            var URLname = ""
            if(termsWeb)
            {
                URLname = "terms"
                termsWeb = !termsWeb
            }else
            {
                URLname = "another"
                termsWeb = !termsWeb
            }

            let html = try String(contentsOfFile: termsFilePath!)
            webView.loadData(html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, MIMEType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL(string: URLname)!)
        }catch
        {

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    internal func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {

        //url name another will show in landscape mode
        if(request.URL?.absoluteString == "file://terms")
        {
            print(request.description)

            if(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation != UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
            {
                let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
                self.validOrientation = .Landscape
                UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
            }
        }

        //url name another will show in all modes
        if(request.URL?.absoluteString == "file://another")
        {
           self.validOrientation = .All
        }

        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.validOrientation
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Reinier, I will soon try this! I let you know!

Comment: If you have any question please let me know

Comment: See my "update" in my post. What did I forget? Or what do I wrong?

Comment: I will review my answer again, so you want to force landscape and keep on landscape?

Comment: @LaurensV you had implemented `func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool`?